# The number of ways of dividing a number by three separate integers.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways can I arrive at the number $45$ by exactly using $5$, $10$ and $20$.  I can use each number as many times as necessary. (e.g $9×5$, $20+(5×5)$) this leads to the question, if the number wasn't $45$ but $x$ is there a general formula to answer the above question from number $a$, $b$ and $c$? (where $a$, $b$ and $c$ may not be whole numbers) - Many thanks!

Comment: This is not really about permutations, is it? In a permutation one only rearranges, no duplication of a same value.

Comment: Also, do you consider $(5\times5)+20$ to be different from $20+(5\times5)$, and/or from $(2\times5)+20+(3\times5)$?

Comment: Apologies for the wrong tag, I am not great with Maths (though I try).  I'm looking at a radio frequency bandwidth of 45MHz.  We have 4G 'signals' with bandwidths of 5MHz, 10MHz and 20MHz to go into this bandwidth. How many different combinations using 5,10 and 20 (which can be used as many times as one pleases but only with addition) can be used to fill this 45MHz bandwidth.  Moreover, is there a methodology/formula to determine the number of combinations for a given total bandwidth and the number of bandwidths we can squeeze in (even if bandwidth unused) (eg 22 total with 15.2 and 3.3).

Answer (score 0):

There is a methodology/formula, as you say. It might not be completely satisfactory for you because it is recursive. As far as solving the recursion, since I learned it in an algorithmics/complexity context, my focus was not there; an experienced combinatorist would have to give their input on that front.

Define a recursive function $f:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ by $$f(x,a) = \left\{\begin{align}&0, \quad &x < 0 \\ &1,\quad &x = 0 \\ &f(x-a,a),\quad &\text{otherwise}\end{align}\right.$$
What this formula returns is $1$ if $a$ is a multiple of $x$, and $0$ if not. Another way of looking at this, to put it in your context, is that it returns the "number of ways" of getting $x$ by just using $a$. Granted, this can only be $0$ or $1$, but in this view we can use the function as inspiration to get the result you want.

Now say we have a collection of integers $A =\{a_1,\dots,a_s\}$. A first approach might be to add up all the $f(x,a_i)$, but this would only give the result "how many ways can we get $x$ by using a single $a_i$ at a time". Thus, we need $f$ to "branch out" at each level of the recursion. This is achieved by a new function $F_A:\Bbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ defined as $$F_A(x) = \left\{\begin{align}&0, \quad &x < 0 \\ &1,\quad &x = 0 \\ &\sum_{i=1}^sF_A(x-a_i),\quad &\text{otherwise}\end{align}\right.$$
This gives the desired result. The proof is based on induction and is a bit heavy, but let's just see that it works for $x = 12$, $A =\{2,5\}$. I've dropped the $A$ subindex, same colors indicate which expression has been expanded, and I reassign color once to make further expansions clearer:

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}F(12) &= \color{red}{F(10)} + \color{blue}{F(7)} \\ &=\color{red}{F(8) + F(5)}+ \color{blue}{F(5) + F(2)} \\ &= \color{green}{F(8)} + \color{purple}{F(5)} + \color{orange}{F(5)}+\color{fuchsia}{F(2)} \end{align} \\=\color{green}{F(3) + F(6)} + \color{purple}{F(0) + F(3)}+\color{orange}{F(0) + F(3)}+\color{fuchsia}{\cancel{F(-3)} + F(0)}$$
Obviously all the $F(3)$s won't reach exactly $0$, so I'll drop them now: $$\require{cancel}\begin{align}\dots&=\color{green}{F(4) + F(1)}+\color{purple}{1}+\color{orange}{1}+\color{fuchsia}{1} \\ &=\color{green}{\cancel{F(-1)}+F(2)}+\color{orange}{\cancel{F(-4)+F(-1)}} + 3 \\&=\color{green}{\cancel{F(-3)}+F(0)} + 3 \\ &= 1 + 3 = \fbox{4}\end{align}$$
This coincides with what we know already: $$\begin{align}12 &= 5+5+2 \\&= 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2\end{align}$$
taking into account that our formula counts $5 + 5 + 2, 5+2+5,2+5+5$ as three different sums. To solve this, we modify the recursion to only count ordered sums (with this we have to add a second argument): $$\mathrm F_A(x,a_j) = \left\{\begin{align}&0, \quad &x < 0 \\ &1,\quad &x = 0 \\ &\sum_{\substack{i=1 \\ a_i\geq a_j}}^s\mathrm F_A(x-a_i,a_i),\quad &\text{otherwise}\end{align}\right.$$

The result we want is then simply $$\sum_{j=1}^s\mathrm F_A(x,a_j)$$ i.e. the above formula gives the number of ways to obtain $x$ by adding numbers in the set $A$. Check for yourself that this works with $12$ and $\{2,5\}$!

The formulas might be a bit obscured by the notation, I will admit. In any case the "algorithm" should be very intuitive: start with the total amount $x$, and subtract from it numbers in the collection in every possible way, and every time you reach $0$, add $1$ to the total count.

For related info, read up on the [change-problem](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change).